# How to set a $location.path to my previous location if it was stored in a cookie?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

The old project doesn't use any `$location.path()` for redirection and now I have to modify the project by changing all `window.location` to `$location.path()`.

But in this function, I cant change it correctly.

```
$scope.goBack = function () {
    //window.location.href = $cookieStore.get('previous_location');

    $location.path($cookieStore.get('previous_location'))
}
```

Cookie containing the value : `ttp%3A//abc-bcd-000.abhindia.in/reachout/app/forms/list%22`

Comment: Do you get any kind of console error?

Comment: what exactly is not working? Did you forget to inject the $location in your controller? You may also be checking the format of the string.

Comment: Actually i have resolved the issue by instead of storing the entire URL in to the cookie i just stored the last two segment. Now its worked fine and thanks for your supports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have inject $location to your component.

If you want to decode the uri you can use global function

```
var uri = "ttp%3A//fts-dsk-141.ftsindia.in/reachout/app/forms/list%22";
var dec = decodeURI(uri);
```

Comment: how can i get the last two segment like 'forms/list' by using this function?

Comment: you can use split function`var link = dec.split('/');`
`var lastTwoSegments = link[link.length-2]+"/"+link[link.length-1];`